# Very weird memory use

Tags: ram, disk-usage, log

out of nowhere my ubuntu 22.00 complained that it's memory was full. After some investigation I came across something really, really weird. Potentially worring.

I listed the use of the various dirs in order to try and clean up the system and this is what I found.

cd /
sudo du -xhd1

```
4,0K    ./srv
2,5M    ./root
248K    ./tmp
304M    ./opt
6,3G    ./home
8,0K    ./media
18M ./etc
4,0K    ./mnt
16K ./lost+found
84K ./snap
4,0K    ./cdrom
6,7G    ./usr
475G    ./var
174M    ./boot
491G    .
```

cd var
sudo du -xhd1

```
454G    ./log
52K ./spool
153M    ./cache
92K ./tmp
29M ./crash
21G ./lib
176K    ./backups
4,0K    ./opt
4,0K    ./mail
4,0K    ./metrics
2,3M    ./snap
4,0K    ./local
475G    .
```

cd log
sudo du -xhd1

```
4,0K    ./gdm3
4,0K    ./openvpn
8,0K    ./hp
4,1G    ./journal
1,4M    ./installer
24K ./unattended-upgrades
76K ./cups
4,0K    ./speech-dispatcher
26M ./calico
20K ./postgresql
540K    ./apt
4,0K    ./private
32K ./letsencrypt
36K ./sysstat
444K    ./pods
4,0K    ./dist-upgrade
44K ./containers
455G    .
```

As you can see my log folder is insanely overflowing. But when I list its content, IT DOESN'T EVEN ADD UP!

What the hell is going on?
Please, if you have **any** idea, let me know. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 22.00 release. It looks like you are asking about disk space, not about "memory". What do you mean by "when I list its content, IT DOESN'T EVEN ADD UP!"? Please [edit] the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Please clarify your question;  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, 22.00 means 2022 and 00 is not a valid month (01 - 12 are expected months, but releases don't occur every month).  Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Your command syntax is only looking at directories within /var/log. You need to include the files. There is likely a better way but try `sudo du -xhd1 *`

Comment: You have log files in the /var/log directory that are adding up to 455G.  I would run a `ls -al` from the `/var/log` directory so that you can see the largest log files.  Then I would look into why those files are so large.  You might be experiencing a hardware failure.

Comment: Your Question title complains about "Memory" but  in the text you examine disk space. Use `df` or `sudo du -sk /*`. Read `man df du`.  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much everyone for the suggestions, ultimately, since luckily I  was able to store everything safely I deleted the partition. I am very inclined to belive that I was experiencing some sort of hardware failure. I may have miscinfigured the dual boot with windows, because I have always used Linux on older computers, and it was very strangely acting up lately. I may retry dual booting and being more careful in the process

Comment: Without examining the log files it will be difficult to say exactly what was going on.  The acting strangely lately could have been due to the drive being full.  I did in the past have a drive that was going bad and the logs were filling up with sector write failures but yet the drive was passing SMART and other tests that I was throwing at it.  The drive finally kicked the bucket but it never tripped the SMART tests.  In the future I would recommend that you look at the logs before deleting an entire partition to confirm any suspicions you may have.

Comment: Yes, good point. If it ever happens again (hopefully not though) I will first take a look at the logs. Thank you @Terrance